# How to display toaster notification in box in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Expected output is like

[Expected output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVO9W.png)

**Views.py**

```
def UpdateProducts(request,id):
  if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
          data = Product.objects.get(pk=id)
          form = ProductsForm(request.POST,request.FILES, instance=data)
          form.save()
          messages.success(request, "The Subscriber has been successfully added")
          return redirect('/')

        else:
            messages.error(request, "Sorry the data has not been entered to the database")
```

**Html**

```
 {% for message in messages %}
   toastr.{{ message.tags }}({{ message }});
 {% endfor %}
```

please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Add the image directly to the post. What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: i dont have  10 reputation  so cannot able to post image. actually that toaster should display in box with close button and also it should auto hide within 15 seconds